# Inverting an array of arrays (matrix) in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, for-loop, matrix, transpose

I have "text" which is an array of arrays, let's say:

```
1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9
```

and I just want to create another array of arrays but like this:

```
1 4 7

2 5 8

3 6 9
```

I cant get it working. It says: `undefined method '[]=' for nil:NilClass`

```
vect = Array.new()
3.times{|i|
    3.times{|j|
        vect[j][i] = text[i][j]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"text" is not a very good name for an array of arrays containing integers. That said, you might want to look into  [array.transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose).

Comment: Way better! thanks! ("text" is because the array is actually cripted text)

Answer (score 2):

You declare an empty array, but you don't fill it in with empty arrays.

Because the array you are using is empty, `vect[j]` will always return `nil` and not an array as you expect.

Here is the corrected code:

```
vect = [[], [], [], []]
4.times do |i|
    4.times do |j|
        vect[j][i] = text[i][j]
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also you the [Matrix](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) class for those purposes, for instance:

```
require 'matrix'
m1 = Matrix[[1,2,3], [4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

m1.to_a.each {|r| puts r.inspect}  #=> This is just print the matrix in that format.
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]

- Transposed Version -

m1.transpose.to_a.each {|r| puts r.inspect} #=> Note the method `transpose` called. The rest is just for printin.

[1, 4, 7]
[2, 5, 8]
[3, 6, 9]
```